# Orika Mapping for unmodifiable List

Tags: java, orika

I have got two **immutable** bean classes for which I am using Orika mapping to copy the values from one to other.
However, when I am trying to copy the `unmodifiableList` through Orika mapping, it fails by throwing below exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
at ma.glasnost.orika.ExceptionUtility.newMappingException(ExceptionUtility.java:55)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:681)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:650)
at com.myproject.OrikaTest.testEmployeeMapping
```

I have provided the code below with which you can replicate the same issue:

**EmployeeDto class:**

```
public final class EmployeeDto {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> previousGrades;

    public EmployeeDto(int id, String name, List<String> previousGrades) {
        this.id = id;//validations removed
        this.name = name;//validations removed
        //Commented unmodifiableList as it does not work
        //this.previousGrades = Collections.unmodifiableList(previousGrades);
        this.previousGrades = previousGrades;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getPreviousGrades() {
        //tried like this, even this does not work
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(previousGrades);
    }
}
```

**Employee class:**

```
public final class Employee {
    //ditto AS EmployeeDto
}
```

**OrikaTest class:**

```
public class OrikaTest {

    private static final MapperFactory mapperFactory = 
           new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

    private static final MapperFacade mapperFacade = 
             mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

    @Test
    public void testEmployeeMapping() {
        List<String> employeeGrades = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
        Employee employee = new Employee(1234, "John", employeeGrades);

        EmployeeDto employeeDto = mapperFacade.map(employee, EmployeeDto.class);

        //tests using assertEquals
        Assert.assertEquals(employeeGrades, employeeDto.getPreviousGrades());
    }
}
```

I could find a link [here](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/issues/200) on this subject, but it was not that clear as alternatives were not explained properly.

So, can you help with an example or any workaround on how to copy the `unmodifiableList` through Orika mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If the case is that Orika must be able to mutate the list components of the mapped objects then the following could be a work around:

Add a `freeze` method to your objects. When the objects are created they are in a mutable state. After `freeze` has been called it is no longer possible to mutate the objects.

It could be implemented like this:

```
public final class EmployeeDto {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private List<String> previousGrades;

    public EmployeeDto(int id, String name, List<String> previousGrades) {
        this.id = id;//validations removed
        this.name = name;//validations removed
        this.previousGrades = previousGrades;
    }

    public void freeze() {
        previousGrades = Collections.unmodifiableList(previousGrades)
    }

    public List<String> getPreviousGrades() {
        return previousGrades;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we can't ensure that the freeze() method is called (every time after object construction), I mean it is easy to forget to call this method from the developer's perspective.